# How to print excel by command line?

Tags: excel, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I need to print without openning Microsoft Excel. For simple way, we can Right-Click on the excel file.
Windows will display Context menu for choosing Print option from the context menu.

On other way, I we can open excel by command line. like these

```
   "excel c:\Users\loginid\Documents\data.xlsx"
```

But what possible if I need to print by command line. 
What command line for printing?

Comment: There is no possibility to print via command line switches. You can use vbs script or power shell script invoked from command line.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell will do this easily.  You can literally invoke the "Print" verb - doing exactly what Kyoujin recommended, from the command line.  I'm running Win 10 1809, but I believe this is available all the way back to PowerShell 1.0:

```
powershell -command "start-process -filepath .\printermaintenancesheet.xlsx -verb print"
```

In this case, I'm launching a file in the current directory.  If you need a full path, put it in single quotes (since you're using double quotes for the batch call to PowerShell):

```
powershell -command "start-process -filepath 'c:\users\fred\documents\sheetToPrint.xlsx' -verb print"
```

As indicated by Kyoujin, this will open Excel, load the file, print it, and close.  You might want to make sure you set the print area in advance.

Comment: How do you print a specific tab ?

Answer (score 1):

I found [@user193479 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030189/5079799) didn't close excel consistently and was slow/opened the UI etc etc and I am comfortable with VBA so VBS is easy. I created a VBS script which takes the file as an argument and optionally a sheet name. I purposefully omitted "copies" and/or "printer" specification as I can handle that outside VBS via `PrintUI` and just repeating the call to the script. I already have methods for doing this to print PDF/Word etc and didn't want to add more arguments.

print_excel.vbs:

```
Dim XLApp
Dim XLWkbk
Dim ObjArgs
Dim strFileName
Dim strWorkSheetName

Set ObjArgs = wscript.arguments
Set XLApp= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLApp.Visible = False
Set XLWkbk = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(objargs(0))
If objArgs.count > 1 Then
 Set ws = XLWkbk.Sheets(objargs(1))
ELSE
 Set ws = XLWkbk.Worksheets(1)
End If
ws.PrintOut
XLWkbk.Close False
XLApp.Quit

Set XLWkbk = Nothing
Set XLApp = Nothing
Set ObjArgs = Nothing
```

Test:

```
wscript "C:\tmp\print_excel.vbs" "C:\tmp\Book1.xlsx" "Sheet2"
::wscript "C:\tmp\print_excel.vbs" "C:\tmp\Book1.xlsx"
```

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Print+Excel+Via+Command+Line+-+VBA+VBScript+-+Excel.exe+Switches

Also.... Word and PowerPoint have "print" switches to their respective executable... What the heck Microsoft....